# React : issue with format script on OSX

Tags: reactjs

I have a issue with all the example that I find/try under my OSX.

I have install on my OSX MAMP PRO (php 4.2), Symfony 5, Composer, React; everthing without any issue and I have follow a lot of demo and try a lot of script without issue.

But now, is the second time that I have this kind of error.

Script find in demo:

```
  createItem(event, item) {
event.preventDefault();
let data =[...this.state.items];
data.push(item);
this.setState( state: {
    items: data,
  });
```

}

error that I have:

```
Syntax Error: Unexpected token, expected ";" (20:17)
18 |     let data =[...this.state.items];
19 |     data.push(item);
> 20 |     this.setState{ state: {
            |                  ^
21 |         items: data,
22 |       }};
23 |   }
at parser.next (<anonymous>)
at normalizeFile.next (<anonymous>)
at run.next (<anonymous>)
at transform.next (<anonymous>)
```

My env don't accept the ":" after "state" and I don't know why and what I can do ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right way to setState
this.setState( {
items: data
});

Please check https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html as well for future references.